# Doubts in K&R edition 2

Tags: c, c89, kernighan-and-ritchie

**1. 8.2 Page 171 `Low Level I/O - Read and Write`**

```
    #include "syscalls.h"  
    int getchar(void)  
    {  
        char c;  
        return (read(0, &c, 1) == 1) ? (unsigned char) c : EOF;  
    }
```

> Casting c to `unsigned char` in the return statement eliminates any problem of sign extension.

What problem we are talking about here? Why `unsigned char` exactly? What would happen without the cast `unsigned char`?

**2. A7.4.8 Page 204 `Sizeof Operator`**

> When applied to a structure or union, the result is the number of bytes in the object, including any padding required to make the object *tile an array*: the size of an array of n elements is n times the size of one element

What is meant by *to make the object tile an array*? We were talking about  structure and union and suddenly how did this *array* appear here? This one surely looks like a typo but I have already checked [Errata for K&R](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html) for all the queries. So most probably I am missing something or giving my non-native English I am not able to grasp it properly.

**3. A7.17 Page 209 `Assignment Expressions`**

> One of the following must be true: `<snip>`; or both operands are pointers to functions or objects whose types are the same except for the possible absence of `const` or `volatile` in the right operand.

Please explain with code. Something like `int a, b` are the two objects having same type. etc.

**4. A12.5 Page 232 `Conditional Compilation`**

> Text controlled by inactive arms of the conditional is ignored except for checking the nesting of conditionals.

Again, please explain with code.

**5. B1.4 Page 247 `ungetc(int c, FILE *stream)`**

> Only one character of pushback per stream is guaranteed.

Does that mean I can use `ungetc` for only once in a program/software?

**6. B.1.1 Page 242 `File Operations`**

> int rename (const char *oldname, const char *newname)

`rename` is a `stdio` library routine then why it's not in `man -s3 rename` but in `man -s2 rename`? I am using Ubuntu 13.10 BTW.

Comment: Its a series of questions. You need a tutor man.

Comment: Thanks but right now I don't have any. How about helping me on any one of the queries? ;)

Comment: You're supposed to ask a single question. And "can you answer all my questions?" doesn't count :-)

Comment: `rename` is in `2` because primarily it's a *system call* -- OS dependent. This has priority over "standard functions", because if it had not, the "system call" section would be empty. Anyway, asking "why" on the topic of `man` pages usually leads to opiniated discussions.

Comment: @juanchopanza- Posting 6 questions with title `"K&R edition 2 - Doubt %d", i` seemed nuisance to me than a posting single post compiling all the doubts. May be it was a wrong move.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If `EOF` is defined as `-1`, and if in this compiler implementation the `char`  is by default `signed` (it is implementation defined whether an unqualified `char` is `signed or unsigned`; and GCC even allows changing it for many targets with `-funsigned-char`/`-fsigned-char`), then
   without casting to `(unsigned char)`, reading byte `255` would be
   indistinguishable from end-of-file.
2. The object tiling an array means that you have:

   ```
   struct foo {
       int a, b;
       char c;
   };
   struct foo bar[5];
   ```

   That is, array of structs; the size of the whole array is `sizeof(struct foo)` multiplied by number of elements in the array; and corollary, if there are alignment requirements, the `sizeof(struct foo)` must take these into account. On this computers `int` is 4 bytes and `char` 1; yet the structure has size of 12 bytes (`sizeof(struct foo) == 12)`; and the size of array is exactly `sizeof(struct foo) * 5`, not `sizeof(struct foo) * 5 + some`.
3. As I understood this, it means that, all previous ones in that paragraph failing, a pointer is assignable from another, if the types are exactly the same, **or** the left hand pointer qualifies the pointed-to type with `volatile` or `const` that is not present on the right hand type:

   ```
   int a = 42;
   const volatile int *b = 0;
   b = &a;
   ```

   is ok; as the left hand size has type `const volatile int *` whereas the right hand side is `int *`; it is OK that `const` and `volatile` are absent on the RH, wheras

   ```
   const volatile int a = 42;
   int *b = 0;
   b = &a;
   ```

is not ok, because the left hand side is `int *` and RH has type `const int *`; such assignment would discard qualifiers; `gcc` emits a warning:

> warning: initialization discards ‘const volatile’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]

4. it means that if you have

   ```
   #if 0

   // this is the inactive arm of #if
   // the code here is ignored *except* for checking
   // for closing #endif; and #if/#ifdef for nesting

   #if 0
   #endif // so that the preprocessor knows that this #endif
          // does not yet end the inactive arm of #if 

   #else
   // but here is an active arm
   #endif
   ```
5. An `ungetc` must be followed by at least 1 read; it is not guaranteed that you can do `ungetc` successfully right after another `ungetc`.
6. Everything that comes directly from a Linux system call is in manual section 2. `rename` is a system call, though it also does conform to C89, C99.